# How to pass Params to ScheduledMethodRunnable Method

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks

I´m trying to build a method which creates scheduled jobs. These job call a URL.

```
public synchronized void scheduleNewJob(int jobNr, long newRate) throws NoSuchMethodException {

    ScheduledFuture job = jobsMap.get(jobNr);

    if (job != null) {// job was already scheduled, we have to cancel
                        // it
        job.cancel(true);
    }
    // reschedule the same method with a new rate
    final String methodName = "callApi";

    Method method = new ApiCallerHelper().getClass().getMethod(methodName, String.class);

    job = taskScheduler
            .scheduleAtFixedRate(new ScheduledMethodRunnable(targetClass, method), newRate);
```

To do this I need to pass a URI param to my method (callApi).

Is there a possibility to do this? Or maybe a better way?

Answer (score 1):

According to Spring [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/ScheduledMethodRunnable.html) on ScheduledMethodRunnable:

> ...meant to be used for processing of no-arg scheduled methods.

I guess you can create a class wrapper with parametrized constructor. Wrap a class with the scheduled method in it. And the refer to param from scheduled method, while the method itself still would be no-arg and void-returning.